VB.net warning: Cannot access project reference path
seen under the solution explorer
I see a warning sub-icon on the Dependencies/COM for a key and anytime the project is opened I see this warning:
warn: Cannot access project reference path. Is "{bee4bfec-6683-3e67-9167-3c0cbc68f40a}" reference valid? Reloading project might resolve this issue.
reloading does not seem to help and other threads on Stackoverlfow have addressed this but their solution do not seem to apply or work, so I'm guessing this is an idiosyncratic matter. I see this key in a number of places in the registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Interface, and it may be a left over from previous attempts to use invoke ms-excel from withing VB.net which failed... pure guess.
is it possible to find out what this reference is?
Can it be summarily deleted?
Any hints on how to clear this warning will be appreciated.

I'm assuming that you're describing a reference that appears in your project file; I think that GUID is a key into HKCR/TypeLib where the entry describes a registered type library (which could then be used as a COM reference).  If you can't find it in the registry, then it won't be useful to the compiler, so you would then need to either remove it or figure out what it used to be and reinstall it.

Whatever the cause is, close VS, make a backup of the whole "Solution", then reopen, right-click and remove the reference under COM. If the project still compiles and runs then it was spurious.
